# How to write integration tests for dropwizard

Tags: testing, integration, dropwizard

I am developing an application with dropwizard and I need to start my application with stubs and run some integration tests.

Is anyone aware of test framework for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it can be done using DropwizardServiceRule

```
DropwizardServiceRule<ServerConfiguration> server = new DropwizardServiceRule<ServerConfiguration>(Main.class, this.getClass().getResource("/config-samples/test-integration-server-config.yml").getPath())

server.startIfRequired()
```